# How to let kotlin library support java project friendly

Tags: java, kotlin

I create an kotlin library and published into maven central.

However, if this library is used by pure java project, user must add the dependency “kotlin-stdlib” explicitly.

It looks like that the “koitlin-stdlib” is automatically excluded from grade/maven dependency tree because it is treated as provided dependency.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In gradle you can add

```
dependencies {
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

The generated pom.xml should contain this dependency.

See:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.ragin-lundf/bdd-cucumber-gherkin-lib/1.48.0

  - -> under runtime dependencies
- https://github.com/Ragin-LundF/bbd-cucumber-gherkin-lib/blob/main/build.gradle

  - -> as an example how to generate the pom for publishing to maven central in gradle

Comment: I find the reason.

implemetation(kotlin("reflect"))

is not OK,

api(kotlin("reflect"))

must be used.

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason.

implemetation(kotlin("reflect"))

is not OK,

api(kotlin("reflect"))

must be used.